# Spring Web Flux - WebClient - exchange - block - how to release the connection to the connection pool?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

### Current:

I am using `spring-webflux-5.2.8.RELEASE` and this is working "*fine*":

```
httpStatus = webClient
    .post()
    .uri(someUri)
    .headers(someHeaders)
    .bodyValue(someBody)
    .exchange()
    .map(ClientResponse::statusCode)
    .timeout(someTimeout)
    .doOnError(doSomething())
    .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.empty())
    .block();
```

### Issue:

When an *error* is returned, there is no issue, as the connection is destroyed and is not put back in the connection pool:

> DEBUG r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0xa23f78ad,
> L:/127.0.0.1:7524 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8443] Channel closed, now 0
> active connections and 0 inactive connections

But when i get a successful response, the next *post* will fail/timeout:

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or
> terminal signal within 10000ms in 'map' (and no fallback has been
> configured)

As i needed to troubleshoot, I  used a fix connection pool of only 1 connection like so:

```
@Bean
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(){
    
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.create("pool", 1));
    
    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));
}
```

I am guessing(i may be wrong as i am totally new to webclient and the reactive world) that the problem is that it is **not releasing** the connection after successfully getting the response and i think it is due to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html).

> When using a ClientResponse through the WebClient exchange() method,
> you have to make sure that the body is consumed or released...

### What has been tried:

I tried to do a releaseBody() like so(but that does not work as the next *post* is still failing):

```
.map(clientResponse -> { 
    HttpStatus statusCode = clientResponse.statusCode();
    clientResponse.releaseBody();
    return statusCode;
})
```

P.S I need to use the block(). That can't be changed as i need the response to move on, and i just need to get the status code. I am using WebClient, because i read somewhere that rest template is going to be deprecated in favor of ... WebClient. I hope someone can help.

### Update 1:

I enabled metrics and indeed the connection is not released:

> reactor_netty_connection_provider_fixedPool_total_connections{id="1591603494",remote_address="localhost:8443",}
> 1.0 reactor_netty_connection_provider_fixedPool_active_connections{id="1591603494",remote_address="localhost:8443",}
> 1.0

### Update 2

Found this: `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20474`!

### Update 3

I tried with the default number of connections(i.e 500) and i can notice that the number of active connections keep increasing after each *post* i do :-(

> [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider -
> [id: 0x2316e048, L:/127.0.0.1:32787 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8443]
> Channel connected, now 7 active connections and 0 inactive connections

Comment: If your application is a fully reactive application you should under NO circumstances block. This will potentially give you extremly bad performance. `need to use the block(). That can't be changed as i need the response to move on, and i just need to get the status code.` this sentance makes no sense. You should not block, you should flatMap the response

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your inputs. I cant change it to flatMap now and my application is not reactive, just that part using WebClient "is". The worst case scenario would have been to change to RestTemplate, but i think i just found the solution. Anyway, appreciate your reply. Cheers mate.

Comment: Well good that you clarified it. If non reactive then blocking is allowed. I just want to rule out certain things.

Comment: Can you please try `clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class);` instead of `releaseBody`

Comment: `releaseBody` is better because it does not close the connection if data comes through, according to rstoyanchev [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/910). My mistake was that i did not wait for the `releaseBody` to complete before returning.

Comment: i am fully aware of the usages, i still want you to try it to see if there is any difference

Comment: Oh, sorry, understood what you mean. But i can't use what you suggested, because there will data coming in, and i don't want the connection to be closed. I want it to be released back to the connection pool, which it is doing now.

Comment: for future reference, it is documented in the api for ClientResponse https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html
`You can also use bodyToMono(Void.class) if no response content is expected. However keep in mind the connection will be closed, instead of being placed back in the pool, if any content does arrive. This is in contrast to releaseBody() which does consume the full body and releases any content received.` if anyone finds this later

Comment: @jumping_monkey You need to subscribe for `releaseBody`

Comment: Hi @VioletaGeorgieva, glad to find you here, been reading about your answers and recommendations too. Sorry, if i dont understand too much of what you mean, i am very new to this "reactive" thing. As such i posted what i found to be working for me, if you could take a look and let me know if this is what you mean? In short, i am using `thenReturn`. Is it ok? I find it ok, as my connection is being returned to the pool as "inactive" like so: `Releasing channel` and `Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections`. I was not seeing these 2 logs previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is working for me:

```
HttpStatus httpStatus = null;
Mono<HttpStatus> monoHttpStatus  = null;
:           
WebClient webClient = xxx.getWebClient();
:       
try {
    monoHttpStatus  = webClient
        .post()
        .uri(someUri)
        .headers(someHeaders)
        .bodyValue(someBody)
        .exchange()
        .map(clientResponse -> 
            clientResponse.releaseBody().thenReturn(clientResponse.statusCode()))
        .timeout(someTimeout)
        .doOnError(Exception.class, e -> logger.error("An exception has occurred: ", e))
        .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.empty())
        .block();
                
        if(monoHttpStatus != null)
            httpStatus = monoHttpStatus.block();            
}
:

//SomeOtherClass
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
public WebClient getWebClient() {
        
    :
    
    webClient= webClientBuilder.baseUrl(baseUrl)
                   .build();
    :   
    return webClient;
}
```

And i am now seeing this after the *post* is done:

> DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger.debug[249] [reactor-http-nio-1]
> [id: 0x6b0568a3, L:/127.0.0.1:10168 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8443]
> Releasing channel 
> DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger.debug[254]
> [reactor-http-nio-1] [id: 0x6b0568a3, L:/127.0.0.1:10168 -
> R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections
> and 1 inactive connections

Comment: Yes now it is OK :)

Comment: Hi @VioletaGeorgieva, i have a couple of "doubts", it's too long to fit in the comments, hence i updated my question. Could you please take a look when you have some time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general rule I'll recommend you to stay away from `exchange` if you can. Use `retrieve` instead. For example in your use case you can use `.retrieve() + .toBodilessEntity()`

Comment: Ok, i will check it out as I read that retrieve() do not have access to the `statusCode()`. In my other microservice, i need to use exchange(), as i need to read both the status code and the response, so i did that `.flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(typeReference))`, which is fine according to [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html), as i am using `toEntity`. Now, your reply is scaring me, i hope there will be no other "surprise" for the newbie that i am.

Comment: `toBodilessEntity` does exactly what you need - releases the incoming data and gives you access to headers, status code etc. For your other use case you can do `retrieve` + `toEntity`